# How to update data in a new non-modal window after changing the selection to ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a user list in MainWindow. After pressing the preview button, a non-modal window for data editing opens. Updated data are changed in real time in the main window. The question is how to bind the windows so that because the user changes from the list in the main window, he changes in real time in an already open non-modal window.

Answer (score 0):

After chasing one problem after another with your comments, the problem is your code is not well-designed.  Using data bindings (one of the prime benefits of WPF), you can stop chasing your tail with trying to figure out how to update one UI when data changes.  Here is a simplified version of your code that will always ensure the UI matches the data you wish to manipulate.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <Grid Margin="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">Lista użytkowników</Label>
        <Button Margin="3" Padding="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Click="Zamknij_Click">Zamknij</Button>
        <StackPanel Margin="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <!--<Button Name="Dodaj" Click="Dodaj_Click" Margin="3" Padding="10,3" >Dodaj...</Button>-->
            <!--<Button Name="Usun" IsEnabled="False" Click="Usun_Click" Margin="3" Padding="10,3" >Usuń</Button>-->
            <!--<Button Name="Edytuj" IsEnabled="False" Click="Edytuj_Click" Margin="3" Padding="10,3" >Edytuj...</Button>-->
            <Button Name="Podglad" IsEnabled="False" Click="Podglad_Click" Margin="3" Padding="10,3" >Podgląd...</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="Selection_Changed" Name="lv_uzytkownicy" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Imię"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Imie}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Nazwisko"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nazwisko}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Mail"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}"/>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="5" ResizeDirection="Columns" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Uzytkownik> listaUzytkownikow = new ObservableCollection<Uzytkownik>();
        Podglad_Uzytkownika podgladUzytkownika;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lv_uzytkownicy.ItemsSource = listaUzytkownikow;
            listaUzytkownikow.Add(new Uzytkownik("Mietek", "Żul", "sikalafa@wp.pl"));
            listaUzytkownikow.Add(new Uzytkownik("Franek", "Alpinista", "halo@gmail.pl"));
            listaUzytkownikow.Add(new Uzytkownik("Stefan", "Ulążka", "mam.to@o2.pl"));
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Podglad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            podgladUzytkownika = new Podglad_Uzytkownika();
            podgladUzytkownika.DataContext = lv_uzytkownicy.SelectedItem;
            podgladUzytkownika.Show();
        }

        private void Zamknij_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void Selection_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lv_uzytkownicy.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Podglad.IsEnabled = true;
            else Podglad.IsEnabled = false;

            if (podgladUzytkownika != null && podgladUzytkownika.IsVisible)
            {
                podgladUzytkownika.DataContext = lv_uzytkownicy.SelectedItem;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Podglad_Uzytkownika.xaml**

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Margin="3">Imię</Label>
        <Label Margin="3" Grid.Row="1">Nazwisko</Label>
        <Label Margin="3" Grid.Row="2">Email</Label>
        <TextBox Name="imieTextBox" Text="{Binding Imie, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Name="nazwiskoTextBox" Text="{Binding Nazwisko, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Name="mailTextBox" Text="{Binding Mail, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="pierwsza" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Margin="3" Padding="20, 5" Name="Podglad" Click="Podglad_Click" IsDefault="True">Zamknij</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**Podglad_Uzytkownika.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class Podglad_Uzytkownika : Window
    {
        public Podglad_Uzytkownika()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Podglad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

**Uzytkownik.cs**

```
    public class Uzytkownik : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string imie;
        private string nazwisko;
        private string mail;

        public Uzytkownik(string imie, string nazwisko, string mail)
        {
            this.Imie = imie;
            this.Nazwisko = nazwisko;
            this.Mail = mail;
        }

        public string Imie { get => this.imie; set { this.imie = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public string Nazwisko { get => this.nazwisko; set { this.nazwisko = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public string Mail { get => this.mail; set { this.mail = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to solve it like this, but then I get an unhandled exception that reads:
"System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast object of type 'Z3.User_View' to type 'Z3.MainWindow'"

in this line of code:

((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).Process(imieTextBox.Text, nazwiskoTextBox.Text, mailTextBox.Text);

Comment: That's because whenever you edit the "dane" textbox, your Application.Current.MainWindow is now your Podglad_Uzytkownika window, not your MainWindow.  Try changing the code to be `((MainWindow)this.Owner).Process(imieTextBox.Text, nazwiskoTextBox.Text, mailTextBox.Text);`

Comment: Unfortunately, it continues to throw an unhandled exception. I have tried everything and still can't solve this problem.

Comment: Show more code, mainly all of your xaml code.  It's really hard to help root-cause without a fully reproducible sample.  Also, what are you actually doing to trigger the "dane" textbox?  Are you typing something in the text box?  What is "dane"?

Comment: See my revised answer.  After looking at your full code, you never set the Owner property of your Podglad_Uzytkownika window to be MainWindow.

Comment: Unfortunately, when a non-modal window is already open and we click on another user, his data does not change.
And when you close the window and try to open it again, you get an unhandled exception.

Comment: OK, I did a full rewrite of your code that works (see new revised answer).  You're just patching one problem after another that started with problematic coding practices.  I see a lot of issues with your code, and it might be beneficial for you to look into studying my revised solution, understanding data binding, and how to take advantage of simplifying your code using these bindings.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot. Let me delve into this topic.

Answer (score 0):

- WPF does not recommend coding business logic directly in xaml.cs
  files.
- It is recommended that you write code using the MVVM pattern

ViewModel

```
public class podgladUzytkownika : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string imie;
    private string nazwisko;
    private string mail;

    public string Mail
    {
        get => mail;
        set => this.SetValue(ref mail, value);
    }
    public string Nazwisko
    {
        get => nazwisko;
        set => this.SetValue(ref nazwisko, value);
    }
    public string Imie
    {
        get => imie;
        set => this.SetValue(ref imie, value);
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        oldValue = newValue;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private int refreshCount;

    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; }

    public ICommand PodgladUzytkownikaShow { get; }

    public podgladUzytkownika data { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        data = new podgladUzytkownika();
        PodgladUzytkownikaShow = new Command(PodgladUzytkownikaShowExecute);
        RefreshCommand = new Command(RefreshCommandExecute);
    }

    private void PodgladUzytkownikaShowExecute(object obj)
    {
        var window = new Window();
        window.DataContext = data;
        window.Show();
    }

    private void RefreshCommandExecute(object obj)
    {
        // Data updates are passed to the view
        refreshCount++;
        data.Imie = nameof(data.Imie) + refreshCount;
        data.Nazwisko = nameof(data.Nazwisko) + refreshCount;
        data.Mail = nameof(data.Mail) + refreshCount;
    }
}
```

View

```
// MainWindow.xaml
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel1">
        <Button Content="PodgladUzytkownika" Command="{Binding Path=PodgladUzytkownikaShow}"/>
        <Button Content="Refresh" Command="{Binding Path=RefreshCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>

// window.xaml
<StackPanel >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Imie }"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nazwisko  }"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Mail  }"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Demo

```
this.MainWindow.DataContext =new MainWindowViewModel();
```